# simple screen splitter for google cardboard

Tags: google-cardboard

Is there an app for google cardboard that has the functionality of simply splitting the regular phone screen?  Is this something the cardboard API is capable of supporting?  I've searched extensively and can't find an app that does this.

Analogically my question is : Cast screen is to ChromeCast as ??? is to Google Cardboard.

Update: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.chai.cardboardremotedesktop.lite&hl=en isn't quite what I was looking for, but is close enough for now :)

Answer (score 0):

For videos I use [VR Cinema](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mobius.vrcinema).

If you search for a launcher for Cardboard I suggest [Cardboard Home](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dudeofawesome.cardboardhome).

Comment: I should clarify with an analogy.  I also have Google ChromeCast and, although it has a bunch of apps to help with stuff like youtube, it also has the built-in ability to "cast screen".  I'm looking for the cardboard version of "cast screen" if it exists.

Comment: You want cast screen to other phones todo a cardboard-party??

Comment: nope, cast screen to my own phone :)  I want to use cardboard to have a fake bigscreen for regular work.

Comment: I should note that I'm using cast screen as an analogy, not as a literal piece of functionality.  Cast screen is to chromecast as ??? is to cardboard